# Passing an array as props from App.vue to child's child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple Vue application with a Form component on the left side and a Main component that fills the remaining space of the web page.The Main component contains a v-for directive that displays a Block component as many times as there are objects in the PCs array.

The Block component is child of the Main component which is,together with Form component, child of App component (the macro component,parent to all other components).The array PCs is defined in the App component as the objects inside are supposed to be created in the Form component and passed with the $emit (or some other solution) from Form to App (child -> parent).

Below is the code.I don't actually know if I'm passing the array correctly from App to Main and don't know how to further pass it to the Block component.

Essentially,the array is supposed to be passed like this: parent -> child -> child's child.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <Form/>
  <Main :computers="PCs"/>
</template>

<script>
import Form from './components/Form.vue'
import Main from './components/Main.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components:{
    Form,Main,
  },
  data(){
      return{
        /*PCs array currently just for demontrastion purposes has some predefined objects*/
        PCs:[
            {
                key:1,
                name:'office laptop',
                power:1
            },
            {
                key:2,
                name:'desktop',
                power:2
            },
            {
                key:3,
                name:'gaming desktop',
                power:3
            },
            {
                key:4,
                name:'workstation',
                power:4
            },
            {
                key:5,
                name:'mac studio',
                power:4
            },
        ]
      }
    },
}
</script>
```

Main.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Block v-for="PC in PCs" v-bind:key="PC.key" v-bind:name="PC.name" v-bind:power="PC.power"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Block from './Block.vue'
export default {
    name: 'MainDiv',
    components:{
        Block,
    },
    data(){
      return{
        
      }
    },
    methods:{
      
    },
    props:['PCs'],
  }
</script>
```

Block.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="block">
        <p>Name: {{ name }}</p><br>
        <p>Power Rating: {{ power }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'PCBlock',
    data(){
      return{
        
      }
    },
    methods:{
      
    },
    props:['name','power']
  }
</script>
```

Comment: In your `Main.vue` you have defined the prop `PCs`, but in `App.vue` you are passing the `PCs` array to a prop called `computers` instead, which is obviously not defined yet. Using sequences of upper-case letters can be a bit of a hassle with Vue though, as you will have to convert `PCs` into kebab-case for use as a template prop key. You have to switch out the line with `<Main :p-cs="PCs />"`, so you might as well wanna think over your naming scheme as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.I indeed missed the part where the prop was named differently in the child component.I renamed the 'PCs' prop into 'computers' in the Main component and now it's working fine.Idek how I didn't notice it but thank you for your help!